# Error with React JS and Sass-loader with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack

Hu everyone,

I have this weird error when I try to compile my react JS application using this command : `webpack -w`

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1051
# Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

    0   node                                0x00000001009558d1 v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
    1   node                                0x00000001009545e9 V8_Fatal + 233
    2   node                                0x0000000100144b10 v8::Template::SetAccessorProperty(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, v8::PropertyAttribute, v8::AccessControl) + 0
    3   binding.node                        0x0000000107004f0e SassTypes::Boolean::get_constructor() + 296
    4   binding.node                        0x0000000107006dba SassTypes::Factory::initExports(v8::Local<v8::Object>) + 326
    5   node                                0x00000001007900c1 node::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 855
    6   node                                0x0000000100169e96 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) + 378
    7   node                                0x00000001001aae1c v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) + 915
    8   node                                0x00000001001aa3f9 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 281
    9   ???                                 0x000016a6fd6063a7 0x0 + 24906471334823
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Here is the chunk of codes where Sass is call :

```
// add custom css / scss
require('style!css!sass!applicationStyles');
```

in alias of the webpack.config.js :

```
applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
```

And in my package.json file (in dev dependencies) :

```
"node-sass": "^3.4.2",
"sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
```

Does someone know what's wrong here ?

Comment: remove `!applicationStyles`, it's not a loader. And that error is atrocious!

Comment: @AndyRay But am I supposed to call my fill without applicationStyle which is my alias in webpack to call my css file ?

Comment: You should set up a loader for it and require your css file from your app's index.js file or wherever

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on UDemy course which I cannot post directly here.

- As @AndyRay suggests create a loader in webpack.config.js.

  loaders: [
      {loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'], test: /.scss$/ }
  ]
- Install the latest

  "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
- Create your alias

  applicaitonStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
- require the scss

  require('applicaitonStyles');